# Determine the primitive $F(x)$ of $f(x) = xe^{-\lvert x \rvert}$ which satisfies $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = -5$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have tried splitting the primitive into two cases, based on the definition of the absolute value function:

1. When $x \geq 0$ then $\int_{0}^{+\infty} xe^{-x} dx $. Using integration by parts I got: $-xe^{-x} - e^{-x}$.
2. When $x < 0$ then $\int_{-\infty}^0 -xe^{+x} dx $. Using integration by parts I got: $-xe^{x} + e^{+x}$.

After applying the limits and using L'Hôpital rules:

1. $\lim_{a \to +\infty} \left[ -xe^{-x} - e^{-x}  \right]_0^{a} = +1$
2. $\lim_{b \to -\infty} \left[ -xe^{x} + e^{+x}  \right]_{b}^{0} = +1$

Summing both results I got $+2$.

Is the problem correct? if yes, is it possible to modify the intervals to get $-5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you calculate $F$ you don't do definite integrals. So, similar to what you wrote in your question, $$F(x)=\begin{cases}−xe^{−x}−e^{−x}+C_1, x\ge 0\\ −xe^x+e^x+C_2, x<0\end{cases}$$
Here $C_1$ and $C_2$ are some constants. From your condition at $x\to\infty$, you get $C_1=-5$. To get $C_2$, you must put the condition that $F$ is continuous at $0$:
$$-0e^0-e^0-5=-0e^0+e^0+C_2$$
Therefore $C_2=-7$

Comment: Thank you, I can see where I got the concepts wrong